# How To Disable/Hide 2 out of 3 Form Control Button?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 form control buttons on my spreadsheet assigned to macro's. I need 2 these boxes to be disabled/hidden until value in cell A1 is not equal to 150. I have managed to make the below code but it is hiding all the buttons.

```
Sub HideButtons()
    Dim Value As Integer
    Dim Btn As Button

    Value = Range("A1").Value

    If Value = 150 Then    
        For Each Btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons
            Btn.Visible = False
        Next Btn
    Else
        For Each Btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons
            Btn.Visible = True
        Next Btn
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please provide the code you are working right now.

Comment: Additionally to the comment above: *"certain criteria"* is very unprecise, which are these criteria? Also a screenshot can help to explain/illustrate your issue.

Comment: Form control buttons on a sheet cannot be disabled (after XL2010..?) Use .Visible =  False

Comment: @ peh if value in cell A1=150 then button 1 and button 2 should become disable/hide and if A1= anything but 150 then all three buttons should be visible.

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Change()` event to test if the value in A1 changed. Do some research and try something then come back with your code. It is very unlikely that people here will do all the work for you if you tried nothing at all or didn't even do some research before. Please [edit] your question and show your efforts. Reading [ask] might help to improve your question.

Comment: @Peh I did some research and was able to make this code, but it is hiding all the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course your `Each` loop hides each button.

But you can use the button's name to toggle specific buttons only. Eg

```
Buttons("Button 1").Visible
```

hides the button which name is `Button 1`. Note that you might need to adjust the name to your button's name.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ToggleButtonVisibility()
    Dim ChangeVisibilityTo As Boolean

    If Range("A1").Value = 150 Then
        ChangeVisibilityTo = False
    Else
        ChangeVisibilityTo = True
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").Visible = ChangeVisibilityTo 
    ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 2").Visible = ChangeVisibilityTo 
End Sub
```

To run this procedure every time the value in A1 is changed you can use the `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        ToggleButtonVisibility
    End If
End Sub
```

But note that this only works if the value in A1 is changed by hand or VBA. It doesn't work if A1 contains a formula.